# Why event loop is giving undefined while moving from micro task to macro task in NodeJs event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, dom-events, event-loop

While executing the below code I got the output as:

> 1
> 4
> 3
> undefined
> 2

```
console.log(1)
setTimeout(() => {
console.log(2)
});
Promise.resolve().then(() => 
console.log(3)
)
console.log(4)
```

I understand that the micro queue task is executed after the synchronous task completed in the stack and after the execution of micro task(promise call) stack will be empty, the macro task will occupy the stack and will be executed and the stack gets empty. If I am correct output will be:

> 1
> 4
> 3
> 2

I don't know why undefined is present while execution moves from micro task to macro task.

Comment: how are you running this block of code?

Comment: @codemax I am running this block of code in the browser console. Also running as Node Application.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are running the script in the **debug-tools** console. This will explain the `undefined`. That because **debug-tools** console will return the result of the last command (`console.log` in your case).

This is how the code really runs: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-neumann-xwbut?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I am running as Node application as well and getting the same result. How the console will return the result. Can you provide an example?